# Opportunty field update from Opportunitypartner

Tags: apex, workflow

I have a requirement to update the Lookup field on the Opportunity with the Account from OpportunityPartner.

As OpportunityPartner is read only object ,i am facing lot of challenges .

let me know if there is any way to do it

Comment: Oppurtunity partner can be queried and if we are stamping just account Id not sure whats the problem.Can you elaborate a little

Comment: as i mentioned in my Question, I want the Partner Lookup field on the Opportunity to be updated with Account from OpportunityPartner.                                                  I want to know how can i trigger this to happen.               Yes we can query on the Opportunitypartner,but any approach how to achieve the above requirement ??

Comment: I think your question is not very clear, what field exactly you need to update on the opportunity object?

Comment: Ok.                                                            I have an Opportunity and it has a look up field called Partner account .Now we want to update this look up field with the AccountToId from OpportunityPartner object.                                          http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitypartner.htm                               Hope this is clear.

Comment: In a before update trigger you could query the OpportunityPartner object, get the AccointToId value and update your custom lookup field in the opportunity with this value. But that was already said, perhaps you could share the code you have developed and shows the errors you are getting.

Comment: on which object we write trigger,Opportunitypartner is a read only object.I want to update the Lookup whenever an partner is added to the Opportunity. Only solution i see is writing schedule Apex and Update the Opportunity records periodically.

Answer (score 2):

Vipul

this is not possible without the use of an Apex Trigger ( [see success.salesforce.com topic here](http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000HZMKEA4)) as lookup fields cannot be updated via Workflow.

You will need to write some custom apex code in order to be able to perform this.

UPDATED:

The best solution for this will be to use scheduled apex as you are unable to run workflow on the object as desired and there is not the ability to create triggers on the object or to have a roll-up summary on partners for you to use.

You could create a trigger on opportunity and see if you have any updated information? This will only run when the opportunity is updated however and so is unlikely to provide the coverage you need. Therefore I would suggest writing a scheduled class to implement the functionality you want.

Paul

Comment: On which object/Action we write trigger,Opportunitypartner is a read only object.I want to update the Lookup whenever an partner is added to the Opportunity. Only solution i see is writing schedule Apex and Update the Opportunity records periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Write a trigger on the after update of opportunity
Check whether this field has changed its value =PartnerAccount

trigger PopulatePartnerOnAccountFromList on Opportunity (after update) {

for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

i(o.parneraccount!= trigger.oldmap.get(o.id).partneraccount)

```
   OpportunityPartner[] PartnerArray =
   [select AccountToID, IsPrimary from OpportunityPartner where OpportunityId = :o.id ORDER BY isPrimary DESC, CreatedDate];
   if (PartnerArray.size() > 0) {

       o.Description = PartnerArray[0].AccountToID;

   }else{

       o.Description = null;
             }
```

}
 }